# Custom Laravel Service Provider not found in host

Tags: php, laravel

I recently added a custom service provider to my laravel application for cart management , its working fine without any problem in localhost  , but when I upload it to my host I'm getting this error :

```
Class 'App\Helpers\Cart\CartServiceProvider' not found
```

I checked the namespace in app.php and file but its ok unless it wouldn't work in my localhost. idk really what to do. I even used `dump-autoload` but it didn't work too.

My Service Provider :

```
<?php
namespace App\Helpers\Cart;
 
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
 
class CartServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{
 
    public function register(){
        $this->app->singleton('cart' , function () {
            return new CartService();
        });
    }
 
}
```

**Solved**: Linux is case sensitive I needed to change the name of the folder.

Comment: Did you push also your vendor folder on your host? The `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php` should contain the mapping to the ServiceProvider which you create

Comment: yes, I did ! , this service I wrote has no vendor folder it's all in `app/helpers/cart `folder. I guess `app/` folder is added as autoload in laravel

Comment: `app/helpers/cart` should be `app/Helpers/Cart ` unless they are referenced as lowercase in your composer.json

Comment: If your localhost is windows and your host is Linux this would happen because the windows filesystem is not case sensitive like the Linux one is

Comment: Thanks guys it did work I changed it to Helpers ! <3